# Can't Access Firebase Database Outside Of My Wifi

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason I can only read and write in the firebase realtime database when I am connected to the wifi that I created the database on. Do any know a reason as to why this is happening?

I tried to debug the issue, however, my console log is not showing any details when I run the code that pulls a query. (assuming my credentials are correct)

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

var config = {

  apiKey: "********",
      authDomain: "********",
      databaseURL: "********",
      projectId: "********",
      storageBucket: "********",
      messagingSenderId: "*******"

};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
console.log("initialized");
} 

componentDidMount(){

   console.log('before query function call');
     firebase.database().ref().child('messages/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
         console.log('in query function call');
         console.log(snapshot.val())
     });
```

expected results in console log
---initialized
---before query function call
---in query function call
---(snapshot of data in realtime database)

actual results in console log
---initialized
---before query function call

Comment: Is the database URL something on your local network?

Comment: The database URL is a https:// link, does that answer your question?

Comment: The protocol doesn't really matter. I more am wondering if it's a local IP address or something. Like 192.168.1.* or 10.0.*.*

Comment: If it's an actual website then I have no idea. I'm not actually familiar with Firebase. I'm just trying to rule out some basic networking issues.

Comment: The most likely seems that the other network is blocking Firebase. It has some fallback mechanisms from its usual Web Socket protocol to HTTPS long-polling, but maybe that's not kicking in for you. The network tab of your debug tools should typically be really helpful here, or [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#enablelogging) with `firebase.database.enableLogging(true)`.